# How do I declare a Siblings extension on a Fluent model in Vapor 3 where the base and related types are the same?

Tags: swift, vapor

I have a type of data like a folder, and folders can be arbitrarily nested inside one another — a many-to-many relation. To support this, I've built a pivot table (I'm using MySQL) relating `parent_folder_id` to `child_folder_id` (foreign keys on the `folders` table). In Fluent, I've modeled this as a `FolderToSubfoldersPivot` in the same way as my other pivot classes.

I now want to extend my `Folder` type to have a `subfolders` attribute using [Siblings](https://api.vapor.codes/fluent/latest/Fluent/Structs/Siblings.html). The code looks like:

```swift
extension Folder {
    var subFolders: Siblings<Folder, Folder, FoldersToSubfoldersPivot> {
        return siblings()
    }
}
```

This is similar to how I've written `Siblings`-typed attributes for other custom types, which all work. However, for this case Xcode gives the following error:

> Ambiguous use of 'siblings(related:through:)'

I assume this is because of the two uses of the `Folder` type in the type declaration for the `Siblings`. I have tried getting around this a few ways (type aliases, explicit call on the `siblings(related:through:)` method with parameters, etc.) to no avail.

How can I get the `siblings()` functionality to work correctly? Or will I need to re-implement the [Siblings struct](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/blob/master/Sources/Fluent/Relations/Siblings.swift) from scratch to do what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After fiddling around with this for a while longer, I've figured out an answer.

The implementation of Fluent's `siblings` convenience functions can be found in [this highlighted segment on GitHub](https://github.com/vapor/fluent/blob/master/Sources/Fluent/Relations/Siblings.swift#L171-L191). I've copied it below for clarity of discussion:

```swift
extension Model {
    ...

    /// Free implementation where pivot constraints are met.
    /// See `Model.siblings(_:_:)`.
    public func siblings<Related, Through>(
        related: Related.Type = Related.self,
        through: Through.Type = Through.self
    ) -> Siblings<Self, Related, Through>
        where Through.Right == Self, Through.Left == Related
    {
        return siblings(Through.rightIDKey, Through.leftIDKey)
    }

    /// Free implementation where pivot constraints are met.
    /// See `Model.siblings(_:_:)`.
    public func siblings<Related, Through>(
        related: Related.Type = Related.self,
        through: Through.Type = Through.self
    ) -> Siblings<Self, Related, Through>
        where Through.Left == Self, Through.Right == Related
    {
        return siblings(Through.leftIDKey, Through.rightIDKey)
    }
}
```

The issue, I believe, is that my desired usage was ambiguous. The first function in the above snippet is used when `Self` is the right-hand type of the pivot and `Related` is the left-hand type. Similarly, the second function is used when the opposite is the case.

As I was using a type of `Siblings<X, X, XPivot>`, Swift was unable to determine which function was better, since the conditions were satisfied for each.

To fix this, I implemented my own extension:

```swift
extension Model {
    public func childrenSiblings<Through>(
        through: Through.Type = Through.self
    ) -> Siblings<Self, Self, Through>
        where Through.Left == Self, Through.Right == Self
    {
        return siblings(Through.leftIDKey, Through.rightIDKey)
    }

    public func parentSiblings<Through>(
        through: Through.Type = Through.self
    ) -> Siblings<Self, Self, Through>
        where Through.Left == Self, Through.Right == Self
    {
        return siblings(Through.rightIDKey, Through.leftIDKey)
    }
}
```

I used `childrenSiblings` to indicate when you're looking for children of the current type (which are also of the same type), and `parentSiblings` for looking for parents of the current type (which are of the same type). The difference between these lies in the inner call to `siblings`, where the `Through.leftIDKey` and `Through.rightIDKey` are switched in the second function. This is because of how I structured the pivot table (i.e., the left-hand column is `parent_folder_id` and the right-hand column is `child_folder_id`).

The usage of these functions is similar to that of the regular `siblings` functions. In my case in the question, where I'm relating `Folder` types to other `Folder`s:

```swift
extension Folder {
    var subFolders: Siblings<Folder, Folder, FoldersToSubfoldersPivot> {
        return childrenSiblings()
    }

    var superFolders: Siblings<Folder, Folder, FoldersToSubfoldersPivot> {
        return parentSiblings()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pierce Darragh, your self-answer is perfectly fine and it's an entirely legitimate personal preference to use the `children` and `parent` labeling. Another option is to simply make the property names align with how you want to think about things (the primary point still being the reversal of the key positions).

For example, a `<User, User, FollowsPivot>` social media type relation could be expressed as:

```
extension User {
    var following: Siblings<User, User, FollowsPivot> {
        return siblings(FollowsPivot.leftIDKey, FollowsPivot.rightIDKey)
    }

    var followers: Siblings<User, User, FollowsPivot> {
        return siblings(FollowsPivot.rightIDKey, FollowsPivot.leftIDKey)
    }
}
```

without any additional extensions. There are, I believe 4, variants of `siblings()` which can be used directly in the `return`.

Comment: Oh! Yeah, that makes a lot of sense actually. Thanks for the tip!